# NTLM authentication in HttpURLConnection not working in JRE but works in JDK environment

Tags: java, ntlm, waffle

I am using eclipse to develop 2 parts of an application.

The web part provides REST services and requests to the services are filtered using `waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter` which extracts the Windows login information to identify the user.

The client part uses `HttpURLConnection` to send requests to the web part. As I understand it, the Ntlm information is automatically packed into the request.

While I was testing this in eclipse, it worked fine. When I deployed the client JAR it did not work. I get a 401 Not Authenticated.

After a bit of investigation I found that I can reproduce this in eclipe by setting the execution environment to a JRE instead of the default which is a JDK.

I have JRE "1.8.0_201" and JDK "1.8.0_161" installed.

So, simply by changing the execution environment from JRE to JDK I can get the connection to authenticate.

What does the JDK do differently and what can I do to get the client to work with a JRE?

Comment: different cipher suites ?

Comment: @Gab I wondered that and copied the `lib/security` folder from the JDK to the JRE. (I assume everything relevant is in that folder). Problem remains.

Comment: Hi I had the same issue. Something has changed between u192 and u201. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u201-relnotes-5209271.html
I suspect it is this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8211883.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first answer of [How to provide ntlm authentication while calling any url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568189/how-to-provide-ntlm-authentication-while-calling-any-url) can reply to this question. 
With Java 8u201 there is a this new JRE option *jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth* wich is set to disabled by default

Answer (score 2):

I didn't manage to find the difference between the JRE and JDK. Instead, I found this work-around.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.7</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-win -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-win</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample code

```
        if (!WinHttpClients.isWinAuthAvailable()) {
            log.warn("Integrated Win auth is not supported!!!");
        }

        // There is no need to provide user credentials
        // HttpClient will attempt to access current user security context through
        // Windows platform specific methods via JNI.
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = WinHttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(getRestUrl().toURI());

            log.debug("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
                int status = response   .getStatusLine()
                                        .getStatusCode();
                if (status != 200) {
                    log.error("HTTP error " + status);
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + status);
                }

                Type listType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, App>>() {
                }.getType();
                return new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(response   .getEntity()
                                                                            .getContent(),
                        "UTF-8"), listType);
            }
        }
```